# Find and process duplicates in list of lists

Tags: python, performance, array

I'm trying to merge counts for items (URLs) in the list:

```
[['foo',1], ['bar',3],['foo',4]]
```

I came up with a function, but it's slow when I run it with 50k entries. I'd appreciate if somebody could please review and suggest improvements.

```
def dedupe(data):
    ''' Finds duplicates in data and merges the counts '''
    result = []
    for row in data:
        url, count = row
        url_already_in_result = filter(lambda res_row: res_row[0] == url, result)
        if url_already_in_result:
            url_already_in_result[0][1] += count
        else:
            result.append(row)
    return result


def test_dedupe():
    data = [['foo',1], ['bar',3],['foo',4]]
    assert dedupe(data) == [['foo',5], ['bar',3]]
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you could use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects). Although you may want to use it earlier in your code, when you create the list of pairs you pass to `dedupe`. As is, you could use the following in your code:

```
from collections import Counter

def dedupe(data):
    result = Counter()
    for row in data:
        result.update(dict([row]))
    return result.items()

>>> data = [['foo',1], ['bar',3],['foo',4]]
>>> dedupe(data)
[('foo', 5), ('bar', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your list of lists is like this :

```
a = [[1,1], [2,2], [1,4], [2,3], [1,4]]
import itertools
#you can loop through all the lists and count as :
b = a
b.sort()
b = list(b for b,_ in itertools.groupby(b)) #removing duplicates
total = len(b) #counting total unique elements
for i in range(total):
    b[i].insert(3, a.count(b[i])) #count repetitions and inserting in list
```

The counts of elements would be inserted in the index 3 of respective lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is lookups in data structure unfit for this case (list).

To find out count for `foo` you have to do *O(n)* operations. You are doing this for every entry in `data` so you'll have a lot of operations going on.

Instead, you should use data structure with faster lookups. In Python, it would be `dict` or its derivatives.

You could use `collections.defaultdict` with `0` as a default value so you don't have to check if your `foo` is in the dict already or not - you simply increment `result['foo']`.

In fact, this use case is so common that `collections.Counter` implements it and some more things, so you should probably get yourself familiar with it.

So, root of your problem is inappropriate data structure. Speaking of Python, you'd better use `dict` for your `result` instead of `list` - that will give you performance you need - and using `Counter` instead of raw `dict` will make things more readable and also DRY.